# Binary word addition; error pattern

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science, binary-operations

If a word $a =  a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ is sent is sent (this is in regards to coding/IT/etc.-I'm trying not to include any extraneous information) and a word $b=  b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ is received (where the $a_{i}$ and the $b_{j}$ are $0$s or $1$s), then the *error pattern* is the word $e =  e_1,e_2,...e_n$ where

> $e_{i} =  0$ if $a_{i} =  b_{i}$ and  $e_{i} =  1$ if $a_{i} \neq  b_{i}$ .

With this motivation, we define an operation of adding words as follows: if **a** and **b** are both of length 1, we add them as according to the rules

> $0 +  0 =  0$        $1 +  1 =  0$
>   $0 +  1 =  1             $1 +  0 =  1$

If **a** and **b** are both of length *n*, we add them by adding corresponding digits. That is

> $(a_1, a_2,..., a_n)  +  (b_1, b_2,..., b_n)  =  (a_1+ b_1, a_2 +  b_2,..., a_n +  b_n)$

So the sum of **a** and **b** is the error pattern, **e**.

I have shown that this operation is commutative, associative, that the identity element for adding words of length n is $0_n$ and that the inverse of any word $(a_1,...,a_n)$ in the set $\Bbb B^*n*$ (the set of all binary words of length *n* is $(a_1,...,a_n)$.

Now I'm looking to show that

> $a + b  =  a - b$ where $a - b=  a +  (-b)$

And that

> if  $a+ b  =  c$ then $a =  b+c$

Comment: The LaTeX for plus and equal are just the symbols themselves; you don't need a "backslash code" for them.  The LaTeX code for $\not=$ is '\not='.

Comment: @BrianTung Also `\ne` and `\neq` — $\ne,\neq$

Answer (score 1):

Your plus and minus are bitwise XOR. In $\Bbb F_2$ (which you are working in) negation is the identity because $-1 = 1$  The things you want to show follow from that.

Comment: I don't know what \Bbb F_2 isle bit wise XOR. I'm not a computer science guy; I'm worried about the math

Comment: $\Bbb F_2$ is the two element field.  There are only two elements, $0$ and $1$.  Since $1+1=0, 1=-1$

Comment: My book on introductory abstract algebra has not introduced fields yet. I'm just wondering how you go about showing this.

Comment: Even in groups, there is only one two element group.  Let the elements be $0,1$ with $0$ the identity.  Clearly $0+1=1$, so since $1+1$ must be different it must be $0$. Now you know the whole addition table.  Since $1+1=0$, the inverse of $1$ is $1$.

Comment: The conclusion of what you said makes sense to me in that I understand 0 is the identity and the inverse of an element is itself as I stated in the question (I'm unsure however of what you mean by saying that "even in groups there is only one two element group" I don't understand how that's true or the significance of that, and I don't understand why 1+1 must be different) but regardless I don't see how this answers my question; the book doesn't define subtraction or addition of negative numbers so how are we supposed to show that a+b=a-b or that a+b=c is equivalent to a=b+c.

Comment: The point is that if you look at group theory (which is where I think abstract algebra starts) there is a unique group with two elements.  Once you show the operation is associative and has an inverse (you don't need commutative) you have a group.  You can use the uniqueness of the two element group to show $1=-1$, which proves what you want.

Comment: These questions are at the end of the first chapter in group theory so I'm new to it. What I'm not understanding is why it's unique. Do you mean that since there's only 2 elements one must be the identity element and one must bet the inverse? Why couldn't the identity and inverse be the same? Since I don't understand the uniqueness I'm not gong to understand how you can use it to show that 1=-1. I sort of understand the logic though; you could define subtraction similarly to addition with the same motivation of the error pattern but it seems sketchy to define an operation the book doesn't.

Comment: Every element of a group needs an inverse.  The identity is always its own inverse.  When there are only two elements the other one has to be its own inverse.  For any prime number of elements, the only group is addition modulo the number of elements.  For composite numbers of elements there are multiple distinct groups.  You will see all this soon.